# Stored procedure produces different results calling from c# .net

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

-edit- wrote a clearer explanation of what's not working down bottom. maybe just skip to that.

I'm having an issue with a stored procedure I wrote and getting the result in my c# application, yet when I execute it within MySQL benchmark the result returns fine.

Firstly the procedure is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetNextOpponent`(IN p_user_id INT, OUT p_target_id INT, OUT p_target_data MEDIUMBLOB, OUT p_target_rank INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE UserRank INT;

    CALL DeleteOldSearches(); /* TODO remove and call on interval instead of every time*/

    SET UserRank = (SELECT rank FROM world WHERE user_id = p_user_id);

    IF UserRank IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        SELECT user_id, world_data, rank
        INTO p_target_id, p_target_data, p_target_rank
        FROM world
        WHERE
            user_id != p_user_id  AND
            user_id NOT IN (SELECT target_id FROM searches WHERE user_id = p_user_id) AND
            shield < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        ORDER BY ABS(UserRank - 3)
        LIMIT 1;
    END IF;

    IF p_target_id IS NOT NULL 
    THEN
        INSERT INTO searches (user_id, target_id) 
        VALUES (p_user_id, p_target_id);
    END IF;

    /*SELECT TargetID, TargetData, TargetRank;*/
END
```

Now if I call it in WorkBench with

```
call battlecraft_test.GetNextOpponent(1, @p_target_id, @p_target_data, @p_target_rank);
select @p_target_id, @p_target_data, @p_target_rank;
```

I have no issue, get a nice result

```
'3', BLOB, '2'
```

However if I execute it in my app with,

```
        public static bool GetNextOpponent(int userID)
        {   
            MySqlConnection conn = null;

            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();

                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetNextOpponent", conn) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_user_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = userID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_target_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_target_data", MySqlDbType.MediumBlob).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_target_rank", MySqlDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    object a = cmd.Parameters["@p_target_id"].Value;    // null 
                    object b = cmd.Parameters["@p_target_data"].Value;  // null
                    object c = cmd.Parameters["@p_target_rank"].Value;  // null =(

                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError($"Unexpected exception of type {ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn?.Close();
            }
        }
```

The out params are all null.

There are a few interesting cases where I've got results out from my application, for instance most times if I step through each line of code while debugging it works fine, however most of the time nothing happens.

I'm really struggling with this, spent hours on it now - my database knowledge isn't as good as I'd like it to be at the moment and I'm out of ideas, so I'm hoping someone has an idea what it could be.

One of my attempts to fix this I tried not using OUT keywords and instead just returning the field and using ExecuteReader instead yet it still only sometimes works.

If I write another procedure to kind of wrap this procedure like so:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`(IN p_user_id INT)
BEGIN
    call battlecraft_test.GetNextOpponent(p_user_id, @p_target_id, @p_target_data, @p_target_rank);
    select @p_target_id, @p_target_data, @p_target_rank;
END
```

It works when I execute it using Reader, however the first row is always null and the second row has the result. It's a usable workaround but I'd rather get to the cause of it.

Thanks for any response in advance.

-edit-

Even stripping it back I have issues. If I reduce stored procedure to just

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetNextOpponent`(IN p_user_id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT user_id, world_data, rank
    FROM world
    WHERE
        user_id != p_user_id  AND
        user_id NOT IN (SELECT target_id FROM searches WHERE user_id = p_user_id) AND
        shield < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ORDER BY ABS((SELECT rank FROM world WHERE user_id = p_user_id) - rank)
    LIMIT 1;
END
```

And then do it as a reader

```
    public static bool GetNextOpponent(int userID)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = null;

        try
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetNextOpponent", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_user_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = userID;

                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // Un-commenting this makes it work...

                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (!rdr.Read())
                        return false; // returns here

                    var r1 = rdr.GetValue(0); // null
                    var r2 = rdr.GetValue(1); // null
                    var r3 = rdr.GetValue(2); // null

                    return true;
                }
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError($"Unexpected exception of type {ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn?.Close();
        }
    }
```

While executing it in workbench still returns a nice result

```
call battlecraft_test.GetNextOpponent(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to be improved in your code

In the finally block of your try/catch validate and close the connection

Dont use generic Catch as the first level of catch use ("DatabaseSpecificExceptions" or "RunTimeExceptions" or any other Expected expection" and log that to a file or by email to debug furthers

```
  public static bool GetNextOpponent(int userID)
    {   
        MySqlConnection conn = null;
        boolean resp ;

        //we assume that if fails
        resp = false ;

        try
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    if(conn != null)
    {
            conn.Open();

            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetNextOpponent", conn) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
            {
            //Addding parameters to the SQL commands - good comments never hurt

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_user_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = userID;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_target_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_target_data", MySqlDbType.MediumBlob).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_target_rank", MySqlDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                        //you are executing a NonQuery but expectin results ??
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //see comments above
                object a = cmd.Parameters["@p_target_id"].Value;    // null 
                object b = cmd.Parameters["@p_target_data"].Value;  // null
                object c = cmd.Parameters["@p_target_rank"].Value;  // null =(

                        //avoid returns in the middle of the flow until debug works
                //return true;
                        resp = true ;
            }
    }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError($"Unexpected exception of type {ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
    if(conn != null)
            {
                conn?.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```